# Disable ng-click while template is loading

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a bootstrap modal which sometimes takes a while to load its `window.html` template. This modal is opened in an `ng-click` event and the user often has the chance to click on the element several times before the template loads if their Internet connection is slow.

Is there a way to globally disable the `ng-click` events while there are templates loading? Is there any other way to solve this issue without filling my code with code like `if (isLoading) return; isLoading=true; ..; isLoading=false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-click` to enable `ng-disabled`

```
<button ng-click="isLoading=true;" ng-disabled="isLoading" ng-switch="isLoading">
    <span ng-switch-when="true">Loading...</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="false">I can now be clicked again</span>
</button>
```

Then, set `isLoading` back to `false` however you deem appropriate. Perhaps in the `success` callback, if you have one.

If you plan on doing this a lot, you could always create a custom directive.

Alternatively, if you're using Angular+Bootstrap, do yourself a favor and use [UIBootstap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)—Bootstrap directives that are written in pure Angular—no bootstrap.js needed.